# Simple Object Validation in Java

Tags: java, validation

I wonder, what is the best practice for object validation. Is there any extra argument against case one or case two? Is there another way?

I don't search for any validation library, I just want to do simple validation.

**Case One**

```
class A {
   public void doSomething(MyObject o) {
      try {
         validate(o);
         doSomethingUseful(o);
      } catch (ValidationException e) {
         Logger.getLogger().warn(e);
      }
   }

   private void validate(MyObject o) throws ValidationException
   { 
      if (o.getXYZ() == null) 
         throw new ValidationException("Field XYZ cannot be null");
   }

   private void doSomethingUseful(MyObject o) { //some funny stuff }
}
```

**Case Two**

```
class A {
   public void doSomething(MyObject o) {
      if (validate(o)) {
         doSomethingUseful(o);
      } else
         Logger.getLogger().warn("Object is invalid");
      }
   }

   private boolean validate(MyObject o)
   { 
      if (o.getXYZ() == null) return false;
      return true;
   }

   private void doSomethingUseful(MyObject o) { //some funny stuff }
}
```

Comment: No strong preference here.  More significant, perhaps, is what you do to be able to capture multiple validation defects on the same object, so that the user doesn't have to keep trying over and over to see what the next defect is.

Comment: Why does validate on case two have a `throws ValidationException` if you are working with booleans?

Comment: @Damokles probably copy paste

Comment: @Damokles: Typo mistake, sorry. I fixed it now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are just swallowing the exception and if the validation method is only private, then prefer `case two` since you should not use exceptions for normal logic.

If you want to let the client handle the exception, which you should, then use `case one` but let it throw instead of swallowing.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)'s a great article by Joel Spolsky to consider reading. Personally, I prefer the second case. Handling exceptions can become messy IMO.

Comment: nice sharing ! 
article

Answer (score 2):

If you really only do 1 field validation, then case 2 is better, because it's clear what is wrong with the object.

If you need more information about validation error or if you need to pass multiple validation errors, then you can use exception object as a container for passing that additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Well in the second case the method `validate` will never throw the `ValidationException`, so if you want to manage more than one exception (null, wrong format,...), I'd suggest you use the first one so you can return a clear and useful error message.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I think you can design this code is by using Aspect Oriented Programming. The validation code that you have added is some sort of concern which is spoiling your business code. If you use aspect you can avoid polluting your code with validation code. You can refer this article http://www.developer.com/java/5-reasons-java-developers-should-learn-and-use-aspectj.html which shows a use case of doing validation using Aspects.